# Display data from any custom csv file using datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid

The thing I'm trying to do is for my program to be able to display any given csv file, as a table using DataGrid (can be something else, as long as it is a similiar type of display). The main problem is that I haven't come across any solution that does not need a specific class for displaying data (like Person or sth).
For now I'm trying to do something with CsvHelper and using the GetRecords function from there, but I end up having a list of dynamic objects from which I cannot extract their properties and values (but when in debug mode I see that the data is read correctly). Is there a way to do such task without too much hacking involved?

the things I mentioned:

- dynamic solution when we have a class ready: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/building-a-generic-csv-writer-reader-using-reflection
- csvHelper docs: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-dynamic-records/

Answer (score 0):

Strange as it may seem, but the easiest way I know is to use Microsoft.Visual Basic package.

```
    using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

    public static void ReadFromCSVFile()
    {
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"c:\example.csv"))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
            bool first = true;
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                if (first) { first = false; continue; } // skip the header if need
                Console.WriteLine(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2]); // or add to DataGrid.ItemSource
            }
        }
    }
```